# How to add a Root CA Cert for Ruby on Mac

Tags: ruby, macos, ssl, openssl, rubygems

I am trying to find an answer to some simple questions.

1. What certificates does Ruby use when doing SSL? (I assume this goes for `gem` as well)
2. How can I add a root certificate to the trusted set of CA certs.
3. Are there best practices for this? Where is it documented?

**Background**

I am using a mac (Sierra currently), and rbenv/ruby-build for installing rubies.
We have set up an internal rubygems repository using Sonatype Nexus.  The server's certificate is signed by the company's internal root certificate, which I have a copy of.

As soon as I tried to add our repository as a source

`gem sources --add https://our.repository.com/bla/bla`

it barfed about the certificate's root not being trusted.  This is the same issue I encounter when trying to pull from the repository (as a proxy) and would be an issue for any other teams using our gems.  I need a good solution to advise my team and others.

Obviously, I am able to use it if I set the environment variable `SSL_CERT_FILE=/path/to/root_cert.pem`.  But I would prefer to place the cert file in a trusted location and let it work transparently as I would for Java trust stores.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From some investigation and experimentation I've realised the following notes. (I recommend doing a `brew info openssl` for this info):

- Ruby uses the system OpenSSL
- Latest versions of OS X don't update openssl as OS X now rolls out its own TLS and crypto libraries
- One needs to rehash the CA file used by openssl

Take a look at the interesting part of output from homebrew regarding openssl:

```
$ brew info openssl
...
A CA file has been bootstrapped using certificates from the SystemRoots
keychain. To add additional certificates (e.g. the certificates added in
the System keychain), place .pem files in
  /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs

and run
  /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/c_rehash

This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because Apple has deprecated use of OpenSSL in favor of its own TLS and crypto libraries.
...
```

So all I had to do was the following, and all my SSL issues went away for Ruby:

```
cp /path/to/my/root_certificate.pem /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs
/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/c_rehash
```

Hope that helps others

Comment: Correct answer for 'net/http' library module that ships with ruby stdlib. Gems can have their own certificates though, and e.g. httpclient gem does.

Comment: Where is `c_rehash` if using the OS-installed version of openssl? The path `/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/c_rehash` does not exist for me on M1 Ventura.

Comment: on an M1 mac the paths are /opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@3/certs and /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/bin/c_rehash