# bundle install hitting ssl issues on ruby 2.3.1 rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, bundler

Bundle install has been running into many issues, and now this error has been like a wall.

App is rails 4, ruby 2.3.1, node < 10, qt@5, must be on a mac ventura 13.3 . These are the requirements for the app as per docs and I have been able to install all of these although was not plain sailing.

I used mac ports and rvm to get ruby 2.3.1 and openssl1, this installs with no errors :

```bash
sudo port install openssl10
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/local/lib/openssl-1.0/pkgconfig rvm reinstall 2.3.7 --with-openssl-lib=/opt/local/lib/openssl-1.0 --with-openssl-include=/opt/local/include/openssl-1.0``
```

As I've been running into this issue for a while I've had time to try some things out, like using a version of xcode 9 (not maintained) and 14(current). Although I don't see why this would change anything anyway? (I'm new to mac and am not actually a fulltime developper)

on running `bundle install` and using an older version of bundler with `bundle _2.0.0.pre.3_ install`
gives this error :

[image: bundle install error report ssl issues]

The error suggests modifying https://www.rubygems.org to http://www.rubygems.org, but this runs into some bigger issues and seems completely unintuitive. Any insight on this is welcome =)

Running `curl -Lks 'https://git.io/rg-ssl' | ruby` gives this info:

[image: report of 'https://git.io/rg-ssl' | ruby]

I have followed these similar SO articles with no success :

- [Ruby on rails : problem of verifiying the SSL certificate while installing bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65437894/ruby-on-rails-problem-of-verifiying-the-ssl-certificate-while-installing-bundl)
- [How to add a Root CA Cert for Ruby on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50540142/how-to-add-a-root-ca-cert-for-ruby-on-mac)

Any tips or experiences would be helpful. I'm not actually a dev as a job, but this is a professional project. I'm not a mac person and have only really worked with small rails 7 projects. Any insight is useful, thanks.

Comment: what is your reasoning for keeping this product? what is the issue with looking at upgrading to something more modern?

Comment: Rails 4 Security Support ended 27 Apr 2017 (https://endoflife.date/rails). Ruby 2.3 Security Support ended 31 Mar 2019 (https://endoflife.date/ruby). Your time would be better spent upgrading to supported versions.

Comment: Hi thanks for your questions. The project is being deprecated and at the end of its service soon, but we still have to make some bug fixes until then.

Answer (score 1):

Something you can try:

- Update your Ruby to 2.6.10
- Add the gem **[Brick](https://github.com/lorint/brick)** into your Gemfile

(To update the Ruby version, it's `rvm install 2.6.10`, and then check both the top of the Gemfile and also the file `.ruby_version`, if it is present, to make sure they indicate this version.  And to add the Brick gem, just place in your Gemfile `gem 'brick'`.)

Brick adds a bunch of forward-compatibility to older versions of Rails, so with only those updates you might be able to successfully `bundle` and run the app.

If it doesn't work then better compatibility is available if you update the app to use Rails 4.2.x or higher (latest 4.2 version is 4.2.11.3, but anything 4.2.x is okay).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response and I will also try this in the week. I haven't heard of brick, but definitely worth a try. I will give it a go and confirm if it helped, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may have an easier time getting this up and running in a VM or Docker container running an older version of your OS, or alternatively, a more "vintage" version of Linux. You'll get best results with something contemporaneous with Rails 4, as in, say, [Ubuntu 14.04](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/ubuntu/14.04/images/sha256-534255069ef3adf1c7a555fd9f614845ab66c61ef9846e438d86e12ae8c89b88).

There will likely be all kinds of issues with expired root certificates you'll need to deal with, but such is the case for obsolete distributions. There's usually a way to patch those in manually, or automatically via a `Dockerfile` that builds on that image.

From there you can hopefully wriggle your way through the upgrade process [step by step](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html).

Comment: Thanks for the tip and had a similar reasoning at first. I think my colleagues would like me to get it up on local machine but as you can imagine, I am spending significant time on the issue that isn't really my main job role anyway. I will put this forward and take it from there. Thanks